# Preventing Windows Server 2012 from adding default route

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus, route

I have a WSUS server on a machine with 4 NIC ports.  I have added a permanent route which "most of the time" forces the WSUS to use the desired NIC to get updates from Microsoft. (route -p add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.50.1 metric 1)

But when the server reboots it automatically recreates a route to the NIC card where the clients connect.  (192.168.1.1) The result it most of the time after a reboot it will start using the other NIC to download updates, which rapidly consumes the cellular monthly bandwidth.  (The cellular NIC is faster.)  I have tried several things, including firewall settings in the Pepwave Surf SOHO router.)

How can I prevent the creation of the alternate 0.0.0.0 route or force the machine to ONLY use the desired port for internet access?

Comment: It sounds like you have a default gateway configured on multiple network cards. You should configure the default gateway only on the network card that you want it to use to reach the internet.

Comment: I think you just hit it.  Ironically, in researching before I posted I found others with the same issue, and a few comments about "multiple gateways", but it didn't click.  I'm testing it now.